# Is it efficient to use relational operators on date or integer values stored in char column in ms sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, datetime

I have been in development for 5 years. But this looks completely new to me. Recently I'm working on Legacy application where `date` and `integer` values are stored in `CHAR` column in `ms sql server`. And the shocking thing (at-least for me because I have never ever thought in this direction before) is that relational operators work with `date` values stored in `CHAR` column.

I'm afraid that this will have a performance issue. Is that correct or I'm wrong? Any implicit casting or conversion will happen in `ms sql server` before applying relation operators? Or this is normal to do in `ms sql server`?

We are planning to migrate this and want to check if I can proceed with this setup or `date` needs to be stored in `DATE` type column and `integer` to be in `int` type column in `ms sql server`?

I also noted that all the dates are stored as string in **"YYYY/MM/DD"** format in table.

Here is the test table that I have created and tested.

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable](
    [Date] [char](10) NULL,
    [Integer] [char](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SELECT * FROM TESTTABLE
```

[image]

```sql
SELECT * FROM TESTTABLE where [Date] > '1993/02/10'
```

[image]

Please advise.

Comment: Relationship don't care about the data type as long as they are the same. `1 = 1` and `'1' = '1'` is true on both counts. But, a big problem with the wrong datatypes is comparisons, manipulations and ordering. `WHERE CharDateColumn >= GETDATE()` will implicitly convert the column to a `datetime`; making the indexes useless. `WHERE CharIntColumn > '9' AND CharIntColumn < '20'` would return no values. Fixing the data types is really important here.

Comment: I suggest you simply choose the data type most appropriate for the data. This will not ensure data integrity (e.g. only valid dates can be stored), the practice will provide better performance by reducing storage size and avoid conversions to coerce desired comparison rules.

Comment: @Larnu but if I try `WHERE CharIntColumn > 9 AND CharIntColumn < 20` it works. Which means a cast will happen?

Comment: Yes, which falls into the problem I mention earlier in the comment.

Comment: Of course, as well, as soon as someone inserts the "number" `'one'` or the "date" `'2019/02/29'` you have an even bigger problrm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't store dates as strings. Use the relevant `date`-like datatype instead.

While a string format like `YYYY/MM/DD` allows you to do equality and inequality comparisons and sorting, other limitations will pop up, for example:

- date manipulations, eg adding or substracting intervals, are tedious with strings
- data integrity cannot be enforced (how to you ensure that your string is a valid date?)

To work around these, you will soon find yourself converting strings to dates in your queries, which is highly inefficient.

Comment: also date comparisons should be faster with binary formats (but not much faster since many string functions are implemented in machine code).

Answer (score 4):

It is better to store values using the correct data types.

However, if dates are stored as YYYYMMDD format -- consistently -- then comparison and ordering operations work fine.  That is, the comparisons as *strings* are the same as the comparisons as *dates*.

If you have an opportunity to fix the data, you can try.  Do be warned that that partial fixes might have a big impact on database performance.  If such columns are used for joins -- for instance -- then the type conversion generally kills optimizations.  Of course, it is fine if the values have the same types in both columns.

If this is a working legacy applications, then just plan on fixing it when the application is replaced.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you're going to have more trouble with Date conversion from different formats, than with performance.

Lets say that your system (or some of your systemS), decide to send something like '1993-02-10', you'd have to "treat" this new string because it's never going to match for your queries.

Coming back to code and performance issues, I've made this quick example to see if we can catch the cost of "Implicit casting", but it seems to be despicable (See the CONVERT_IMPLICIT at the end of the Query plan?):

```
-- Create a temp table to test
CREATE TABLE #TestTable (
    [Date] [char](10) NULL,
    [Integer] [char](10) NULL
)

-- And an index to search for [Integer]
CREATE INDEX Idx_Integer ON #TestTable ([Integer]);

// Create some data
INSERT INTO #TestTable( [Date], [Integer] ) VALUES('2019/01/01', 1)
INSERT INTO #TestTable( [Date], [Integer] ) VALUES('2019/02/01', 2)
INSERT INTO #TestTable( [Date], [Integer] ) VALUES('2019/03/01', 3)
INSERT INTO #TestTable( [Date], [Integer] ) VALUES('2019/04/01', 4)
INSERT INTO #TestTable( [Date], [Integer] ) VALUES('2019/05/01', 5)
GO 100000

// And a unique record so SQL uses the index
INSERT INTO #TestTable( [Date], [Integer] ) VALUES('2019/05/01', 7)

// Select with Query-Plan (Ctrl+M)
SELECT      [Integer]
    FROM #TestTable
    WHERE   [Integer] = 7

DROP TABLE #TestTable;
```

[image]

VS:

[image]

Happy coding!